# radioGroup duplicate my Array when scroll between tabs in setOnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

Friends, I have the following problem. I have a fragment with two tabs (A and B). In tab A I have a listview that in each row shows a radioGroup that contain 5 radiobuttons. What I need is to capture the checked radioGroup in an ArrayList, but I can not do it well.

What I do is that I capture the selected radioButton with the method setOnCheckedChangeListener and, depending on the selected radiobutton, I am adding elements to an ArrayList.

In my custom adapter i have this:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

ArrayList<String> selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();

final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)v.findViewById(R.id.opciones_radio);

final RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        final RadioButton radio2 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        final RadioButton radio3 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        final RadioButton radio4 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        final RadioButton radio5 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);


radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int checkedId) {

                switch (checkedId){

                    case R.id.radioButton1 :                        
                        selectedAnswers.add("1");

                        break;

                    case  R.id.radioButton2 :                        
                        selectedAnswers.add("2");

                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton3 :                       
                        selectedAnswers.add("3");

                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton4 :                        
                        selectedAnswers.add("4");

                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton5 :                        
                        selectedAnswers.add("5");

                        break;
                }

                Log.e("RESPUESTA: ", String.valueOf(selectedAnswers));

            }
        });

}
```

But this causes me several problems.

My main problem is that if I select different radiobuttons and I move from the A tab to the B tab, the Arraylist is doubled.

For example. This code returns:

> E/RESPUESTA:: [1, 2, 5, 1]

If now, i move from TAB A to TAB B and return to TAB A, I obtain this:

> E/RESPUESTA:: [1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1]

It doubled the arraylist twice. 
I tried to replace the setOnCheckedChangeListener by the setOnClickListener, but it does not work well.

Any advice for solve this issue?

Comment: What else is going on in TabA?

Comment: Nothing else. In addition to this failure, if a user selects a radiobutton it is added to the arrayList, but if he later changes his mind and selects a different radioButton, then he should delete the previously marked radiobutton. I do not know how to do this either. These are my two main doubts.

Comment: That's probably not caused by the adapter itself, but by the way you're interacting with the `ListView`. So please share that code with us. Also why don't you show us how you create and maintain those two tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. For this I simply had to replace the .add method with the .set method and place the different radioButtons in true or false leaving the code like this:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int checkedId) {

                switch (checkedId){

                    case R.id.radioButton1 :
                        selectedAnswers.set(position, "1");
                        radio1.setChecked(true);
                        radio2.setChecked(false);
                        radio3.setChecked(false);
                        radio4.setChecked(false);
                        radio5.setChecked(false);
                        break;

                    case  R.id.radioButton2 :
                        selectedAnswers.set(position, "2");
                        radio1.setChecked(false);
                        radio2.setChecked(true);
                        radio3.setChecked(false);
                        radio4.setChecked(false);
                        radio5.setChecked(false);
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton3 :
                        selectedAnswers.set(position, "3");
                        radio1.setChecked(false);
                        radio2.setChecked(false);
                        radio3.setChecked(true);
                        radio4.setChecked(false);
                        radio5.setChecked(false);
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton4 :
                        selectedAnswers.set(position, "4");
                        radio1.setChecked(false);
                        radio2.setChecked(false);
                        radio3.setChecked(false);
                        radio4.setChecked(true);
                        radio5.setChecked(false);
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton5 :
                        selectedAnswers.set(position, "5");
                        radio1.setChecked(false);
                        radio2.setChecked(false);
                        radio3.setChecked(false);
                        radio4.setChecked(false);
                        radio5.setChecked(true);
                        break;
                }
```

Additionally, also cleaning the array when starting the adapter with `selectedAnswers.clear();` so that the records are not duplicated when changing the tab and returning.

There's probably a more efficient way to do it, but that works pretty well.

Thanks you!